# How to import python code in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm trying to import a python code that has usernames, passwords, and auth keys saved to a Jupyter notebook without sharing that information directly in the code. These are just for tests but I've tried using:

```
   import sys 
   sys.path.insert(0, '/C:/user/phlf/saved_data/config.py')
   import file
```

I also tried

```
   %run "~/C:user/phlf/saved_data/Config.py"
```

Is there a way to import python file for Jupyter to use without posting the code directly in notebook?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.path` contains directories, not paths to file.

You'd probably just want to use `importlib` if you know which file you want to import.